# Entity Framework when all data access is done via stored procedures

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

The database architect has mandated that all access to the database will be done via stored procedures. No wiggle room on this. That being said, are there still benefits to using Entity Framework as opposed to ADO.NET to call the stored procedures?

Entity Framework has always seemed to be unnecessary additional layer to me, yet did have some benefits when updating complex sets of objects that might be nested and have complex relationships. However, now that all access will have to be done via stored procedure I am not seeing any additional benefits of the Entity Framework. It seemed to me that ADO.NET is "closer to the metal".

But that is why I am asking this question. Are there other benefits to using Entity Framework when all data access must be done via stored procedures?

Comment: I dont see any benefit in this case.

Comment: Sure - EF *still* converts the row/column and largely untyped output from a stored procedure into **nice** strongly-typed .NET objects for you, and allows you to do things with LINQ queries (on the retrieved objects and lists of objects). It's a bit of a pain to integrate all stored procedures - but I still think EF would have a benefit here.

Comment: @marc_s it would depend on whether they are using stored procedures to read data and do something with it (for example build reports). If CRUD operations are handled entirely within stored procedures, then there is no point in using EF

Comment: @Circular ... do you want to write that up as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: @webworm see below for answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on your data access strategy.

**Are stored procedures used to do a full CRUD operation?**
In this case no data is shared out of the stored procedure so all Entity Framework would do is run it. While that takes only a few lines of code, Entity Framework comes with features such as POCOS, models, mappings etc. which can take thousands of lines of code depending on your database and you will most likely **not use** (Why have strongly typed .NET objects in your codebase when you will never push any data into them? At best they will pop up in Intellisense and confuse your developers). Thus it becomes overhead, not to mention the inevitable learning curve. Instead, you can use the ADO classes to run your stored procedures and the code will be relatively simple and self contained and will be up and running faster than Entity Framework (not much of a learning curve in this case).

**Are stored procedures used to read data? (for example, to create reports or as part of an [OLAP](http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html) system)**
In this case, they will return result sets that will have to be mapped to an object somehow.  You can do this with both Entity Framework and ADO, although it will probably easier and faster to work with Entity Framework, because of the code-generating tools it comes with. Usually data will pushed into a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) which will then be used to implement business logic. With ADO you will still have to create a POCO "by hand" and depending on the complexity of your database, this may be an appreciable task.

**Are stored procedures used for both read-only and CRUD operations?** In this case it's a judgement call with more factors involved (as with all architecture decisions). In general, it's better to be broadly consistent with your data access strategy, so if Entity Framework will provide benefit in one area, then it's worth examining if other areas will benefit too. Keep in mind that some things are not very efficiently done in current versions of Entity Framework, for example batch processing. A decision then needs to be made taking into account the following:

- Database scope (big or small?)
- System scope (high or low traffic? There is a [school of thought](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117357/is-entity-framework-suitable-for-high-traffic-websites) that is cautious about using Entity Framework for high traffic systems if performance is a serious consideration)
- Future development (will the system need to accommodate more CRUD or read-only operations in the future?)
- Learning curve (do you have someone in your team who knows Entity Framework?)

Hope this helps.